# Differentiation of trigonometric function with $\theta/2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Just wondering, what would be the method for differentiating the following:

$$
\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice,

Apply chain rule as follows $$\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)^2$$
$$=2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$=2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$$$=2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the chain rule.

If you need help thinking about what functions you have in your composition, think about what you do with $\theta$ in order to get $\sin^2\frac\theta2$:

$$\theta\mapsto \frac\theta2\mapsto \sin\frac\theta2\mapsto \sin^2\frac\theta2$$

You have three functions:

- $f$ maps $x$ to $\frac x2$.
- $g$ maps $y$ to $\sin y$.
- $h$ maps $z$ to $z^2$.

Now, to get the full composition, you need to think about which ones you apply first. First, you apply $f$, i.e. you first calculate $f(\theta)$. Then, given $f(\theta)$, you calculate $g(f(\theta))$, and after you have that, you calculate $h(g(f(\theta)))$.

Comment: I'm gonna go with using $\sin^{2}(x)=\frac{1}{2}[1-\cos(2x)]$

Comment: @MichaelRoberts The equation you wrote is not correct...

Comment: It's correct now. Typo.

Comment: @Michael Roberts, that's a good method for this example, but the chain rule is a very powerful tool. I'd advise getting to grips with it

Comment: I'm a physicist, I'm here to cut corners.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts When I see $\sin\frac\theta2$, I can immediatelly use the chain rule to calculate the derivative, without needint some addition formulas. On average, chain rule is *very* simple to use and is often the simplest. You just read the functions applied, and backwards, and you get $2\sin\frac\theta 2 \cdot (\sin\frac\theta2)' =  ... (\cos\frac\theta2\cdot \frac\theta2') = ..(..(\frac12))$.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts: Your identity doesn't help to cut any corners since using the chain rule is instantaneous. However, if you want the integral then you do want to use your identity.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)g'$$ with $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\sin\frac{x}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos 2t = \cos^2t-\sin^2t$$
Letting $\theta=2t$ we have
$$\cos\theta = \cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}=1-\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}=1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$$
$$\implies \sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos\theta$$

so
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta$$